# Prefect role deployment

Tags: scheduling, prefect

Currently I'm working with Prefect and learning about it. I saw in the documentation that it's possible to assign and create different roles within Prefect Cloud for the necesarry access control. Now I want to know if it's possible to assign and create these roles via another way other than on the Prefect UI. Is this for example possible via Terraform, config files, API, etc.?

Can someone answer this question, would help me out a lot!

Thanks in advance for taking the time!

Cheers!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Ask if it is possible with a specific technology.

Comment: @possum Well is it possible with Terraform? Because I'm not able to find anything about a Terraform deployment for Prefect :/

Comment: Fair question, automation and source control for some of Prefect is not obvious. Circa 2024 and the Prefect team still plan on developing support in Terraform but it is not ready yet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Prefect Cloud you can use the REST API to create and interact with roles. See REST API details in the [docs](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/api-ref/rest-api/).

Then the [API docs themselves (from Redocly) are also available](https://app.prefect.cloud/api/docs).

Note that you will need to be part of a Cloud organization to take advantage of roles. You can read more about roles [here](https://docs.prefect.io/2.10.12/cloud/users/roles/).

See the screenshot below.

[image]